# Issue skipping song by requester

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm currently working on a music cog for my bot and I'm trying to figure out how to allow the song requester to skip the song without having to use the vote.

The music cog uses reactions to skip, stop, pause songs ect. The `requester` is the user who requested the song.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 if control == 'skip':
            requester = self.requester
            if requester:
                vc.stop()
                await channel.send('Requester skipped the song,')
            else:
                await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
                if react.count >= 5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
                    vc.stop()
                    await channel.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)
```

I'm having an issue mainly with defining the song requester `requester = self.requester`

Here's snippet of the part of the code that defines requester:

```
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
    super().__init__(source)
    self.requester = requester

    self.title = data.get('title')

    if self.title is None:
        self.title = "No title available"

    self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')
    self.thumbnail = data.get('thumbnail')

    if self.thumbnail is None:
        self.thumbnail = "http://ppc.tools/wp-content/themes/ppctools/img/no-thumbnail.jpg"

    self.duration = data.get('duration')

    if self.duration is None:
        self.duration = 0

    self.uploader = data.get('uploader')

    if self.uploader is None:
        self.uploader = "Unkown"

    # YTDL info dicts (data) have other useful information you might want
    # https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

def __getitem__(self, item: str):
    """Allows us to access attributes similar to a dict.

    This is only useful when you are NOT downloading.
    """
    return self.__getattribute__(item)

@classmethod
async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]

    await ctx.send(f':notes: **{data["title"]} added to the queue.**')

    if download:
        source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    else:
        return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

@classmethod
async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
    """Used for preparing a stream, instead of downloading.

    Since Youtube Streaming links expire."""
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    requester = data['requester']

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)


class MusicPlayer:
"""A class which is assigned to each guild using the bot for Music.

This class implements a queue and loop, which allows for different guilds to listen to different playlists
simultaneously.

When the bot disconnects from the Voice it's instance will be destroyed.
"""

__slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_ctxs', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume', 'buttons', 'music', 'music_controller', 'restmode')

def __init__(self, ctx):

    self.buttons = {'⏯': 'rp',
                    '⏭': 'skip',
                    '➕': 'vol_up',
                    '➖': 'vol_down',
                    '': 'thumbnail',
                    '⏹': 'stop',
                    'ℹ': 'queue',
                    '❔': 'tutorial'}

    self.bot = ctx.bot
    self._guild = ctx.guild
    self._ctxs = ctx
    self._channel = ctx.channel
    self._cog = ctx.cog

    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
    self.next = asyncio.Event()

    self.np = None
    self.volume = .5
    self.current = None
    self.music_controller = None

    ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

async def buttons_controller(self, guild, current, source, channel, context):
    vc = guild.voice_client
    vctwo = context.voice_client

    for react in self.buttons:
        await current.add_reaction(str(react))

    def check(r, u):
        if not current:
            return False
        elif str(r) not in self.buttons.keys():
            return False
        elif u.id == self.bot.user.id or r.message.id != current.id:
            return False
        elif u not in vc.channel.members:
            return False
        elif u.bot:
            return False
        return True

    while current:
        if vc is None:
            return False

        react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        control = self.buttons.get(str(react))

        if control == 'rp':
            if vc.is_paused():
                vc.resume()
            else:
                vc.pause()
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'skip':
            requester = self.requester
            if requester:
                vc.stop()
                await channel.send('Requester skipped the song,')
            else:
                await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
                if react.count >= 5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
                    vc.stop()
                    await channel.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)


        if control == 'stop':
            mods = get(guild.roles, name="Mods")
            for member in list(guild.members):
                if mods in member.roles:
                    await context.invoke(self.bot.get_command("stop"))
                    return
            else:
                await channel.send(':raised_hand:  **Only a mod can stop and clear the queue. Try skipping the song instead.**', delete_after=5)
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_up':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume += 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_down':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume -= 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'thumbnail':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).set_image(url=source.thumbnail).set_footer(text=f"Requested By: {source.requester} | Video Thumbnail: {source.title}", icon_url=source.requester.avatar_url), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'tutorial':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).add_field(name="How to use the music controller?", value="⏯ - Pause\n⏭ - Skip\n➕ - Increase Volume\n➖ - Increase Volume\n - Get Thumbnail\n⏹ - Stop & Leave\nℹ - Queue\n❔ - Display help for music controls"), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'queue':
            await self._cog.queue_info(context)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)
```

If anyone could help me an example of what I'm doing wrong would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: ...and?  What exactly isn't working about this?

Comment: It seems to be when defining requester in `if control == 'skip':` it doesn't seem to skip the song. Maybe there is an simple indentation issue then? Because `requester = self.requester` looks to be the right way to define the requester?

Comment: I've expanded my explanation (see my answer)  on this again I'm not sure why your answer is not working here.

Comment: There are a few places it could be going wrong.  Could you do a little more investigation?  1. The skip reaction isn't being detected, maybe because `check` is filtering it out somehow. 2. The `requester` and `user` are different types (a `User` and a `Member` maybe) and that makes comparing them not work (I'm pretty sure this isn't it) 3. `requester` doesn't have the value we think it does. Could you add a `print(react, control, type(user), user.id, type(self.requester), self.requester.id)` just before the `if control == 'skip'` line?

Comment: Just before? unfortunately thats not printing anything in the console. I'll have a look to see if it's a check issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking `requester` against the `user` that reacted to the message.

```
if control == 'skip':
    if self.requester == user:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

With your current code, I would expect the song to always be skipped, as any `User` or `Member` object it truthy.  You should double-check what is actually being assigned to `self.requester`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, though should it be `if self.requester == requester:`  as is defined as `self.requester = requester` 4th line down. Still having no luck.

Comment: That would make no sense.  There's no reason to define a separate `requester`, just use `self.requester`.  You need to compare `self.requester`, the person who requested the song, with `user`, the person who reacted to the message.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Here is how I'm doing it with your answer, however when the skip  `'⏭': 'skip',` reaction is used it doesn't skip the requester song and causes all the reactions to not function.

Here is the full code:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
import itertools, datetime
import sys
import traceback
from async_timeout import timeout
from functools import partial
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
from cogs.utils.opus_loader import load_opus_lib
from .utils import checks
from discord.utils import get

import asyncio

if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
load_opus_lib()


ytdlopts = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
'restrictfilenames': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'nocheckcertificate': True,
'ignoreerrors': False,
'logtostderr': False,
'quiet': True,
'no_warnings': True,
'default_search': 'auto',
'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpegopts = {
'before_options': '-nostdin -preset ultrafast',
'options': '-vn -threads 1'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    """Custom Exception class for connection errors."""


class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
    super().__init__(source)
    self.requester = requester

    self.title = data.get('title')

    if self.title is None:
        self.title = "No title available"

    self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')
    self.thumbnail = data.get('thumbnail')

    if self.thumbnail is None:
        self.thumbnail = "http://ppc.tools/wp-content/themes/ppctools/img/no-thumbnail.jpg"

    self.duration = data.get('duration')

    if self.duration is None:
        self.duration = 0

    self.uploader = data.get('uploader')

    if self.uploader is None:
        self.uploader = "Unkown"

    # YTDL info dicts (data) have other useful information you might want
    # https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

def __getitem__(self, item: str):
    """Allows us to access attributes similar to a dict.

    This is only useful when you are NOT downloading.
    """
    return self.__getattribute__(item)

@classmethod
async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]

    await ctx.send(f':notes: **{data["title"]} added to the queue.**')

    if download:
        source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    else:
        return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

@classmethod
async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
    """Used for preparing a stream, instead of downloading.

    Since Youtube Streaming links expire."""
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    requester = data['requester']

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)


class MusicPlayer:
"""A class which is assigned to each guild using the bot for Music.

This class implements a queue and loop, which allows for different guilds to listen to different playlists
simultaneously.

When the bot disconnects from the Voice it's instance will be destroyed.
"""

__slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_ctxs', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume', 'buttons', 'music', 'music_controller', 'restmode')

def __init__(self, ctx):

    self.buttons = {'⏯': 'rp',
                    '⏭': 'skip',
                    '➕': 'vol_up',
                    '➖': 'vol_down',
                    '': 'thumbnail',
                    '⏹': 'stop',
                    'ℹ': 'queue',
                    '❔': 'tutorial'}

    self.bot = ctx.bot
    self._guild = ctx.guild
    self._ctxs = ctx
    self._channel = ctx.channel
    self._cog = ctx.cog

    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
    self.next = asyncio.Event()

    self.np = None
    self.volume = .5
    self.current = None
    self.music_controller = None

    ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

async def buttons_controller(self, guild, current, source, channel, context):
    vc = guild.voice_client
    vctwo = context.voice_client

    for react in self.buttons:
        await current.add_reaction(str(react))

    def check(r, u):
        if not current:
            return False
        elif str(r) not in self.buttons.keys():
            return False
        elif u.id == self.bot.user.id or r.message.id != current.id:
            return False
        elif u not in vc.channel.members:
            return False
        elif u.bot:
            return False
        return True

    while current:
        if vc is None:
            return False

        react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        control = self.buttons.get(str(react))

        if control == 'rp':
            if vc.is_paused():
                vc.resume()
            else:
                vc.pause()
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'skip':
            if self.requester == user:
                await channel.send('Requester skipped.')
                vc.stop()
            else:
                await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
            if react.count >= 5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
                vc.stop()
            await channel.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)


        if control == 'stop':
            mods = get(guild.roles, name="Mods")
            for member in list(guild.members):
                if mods in member.roles:
                    await context.invoke(self.bot.get_command("stop"))
                    return
            else:
                await channel.send(':raised_hand:  **Only a mod can stop and clear the queue. Try skipping the song instead.**', delete_after=5)
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_up':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume += 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_down':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume -= 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'thumbnail':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).set_image(url=source.thumbnail).set_footer(text=f"Requested By: {source.requester} | Video Thumbnail: {source.title}", icon_url=source.requester.avatar_url), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'tutorial':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).add_field(name="How to use the music controller?", value="⏯ - Pause\n⏭ - Skip\n➕ - Increase Volume\n➖ - Increase Volume\n - Get Thumbnail\n⏹ - Stop & Leave\nℹ - Queue\n❔ - Display help for music controls"), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'queue':
            await self._cog.queue_info(context)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)


async def player_loop(self):
    """Our main player loop."""
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

    while not self.bot.is_closed():
        self.next.clear()

        try:
            async with timeout(3500):
                source = await self.queue.get()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return self.destroy(self._guild)

        if not isinstance(source, YTDLSource):
            # Source was probably a stream (not downloaded)
            # So we should regather to prevent stream expiration
            try:
                source = await YTDLSource.regather_stream(source, loop=self.bot.loop)
            except Exception as e:
                await self._channel.send(f'An error occured!.\n'
                                         f'```css\n[{e}]\n```')
                continue

        source.volume = self.volume
        self.current = source
        try:
            self._guild.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda _: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.next.set))
        except Exception:
            continue
        embednps = discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E)
        embednps.add_field(name="Currently Playing:", value=f"```fix\n{source.title}```", inline=False)
        embednps.add_field(name="Requested By:", value=f"**{source.requester}**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Source:", value=f"**[URL]({source.web_url})**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Uploader:", value=f"**{source.uploader}**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Duration:", value=f"**{datetime.timedelta(seconds=source.duration)}**", inline=True)
        embednps.set_thumbnail(url=source.thumbnail)
        self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embednps)

        self.music_controller = self.bot.loop.create_task(self.buttons_controller(self._guild, self.np, source, self._channel, self._ctxs))
        await self.next.wait()

        # Make sure the FFmpeg process is cleaned up.
        source.cleanup()
        self.current = None

        try:
            # We are no longer playing this song...
            await self.np.delete()
            self.music_controller.cancel()
        except Exception:
            pass

def destroy(self, guild):
    """Disconnect and cleanup the player."""
    return self.bot.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))

class Music:
    """Music cog for UKGBot."""

__slots__ = ('bot', 'players', 'musictwo', 'music_controller')

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.players = {}

async def cleanup(self, guild):
    try:
        await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        del self.players[guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        pass

async def __local_check(self, ctx):
    """A local check which applies to all commands in this cog."""
    if not ctx.guild:
        raise commands.NoPrivateMessage
    return True

async def cleanup(self, guild):
    try:
        await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        del self.players[guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        pass

async def __error(self, ctx, error):
    """A local error handler for all errors arising from commands in this cog."""
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        try:
            return await ctx.send(':notes: Command cannot be used in DM.')
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
    elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
        await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel first!")

    print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

def get_player(self, ctx):
    """Retrieve the guild player, or generate one."""
    try:
        player = self.players[ctx.guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        player = MusicPlayer(ctx)
        self.players[ctx.guild.id] = player

    return player

@commands.command(name='stop', aliases=[ 'l', 'disconnect'])
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def disconnect_(self, ctx):
    """Stops and leaves the voice channel."""

    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    except AttributeError:
        await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    if not ctx.guild.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send(':notes: I\'m not connected to the voice channel.', delete_after=20)

    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send(':wave: Stopped and left the channel.', delete_after=20)



@commands.command(name='reconnect', aliases=['rc'])
async def reconnect_(self, ctx):
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    if ctx.guild.voice_client:
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()

    await channel.connect()



@commands.command(name='connect', aliases=['join','summon'])
async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    """connectss to a voice channel."""  
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    await channel.connect()

@commands.command(name='skip', aliases=['sk'])
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def skip_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    """Skips a song (Mods)."""  
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    ctx.guild.voice_client.stop()
    await ctx.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)




@commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing', 'p'])
async def play_(self, ctx, *, search: str):
    """searches for and plays a song."""

    await ctx.trigger_typing()

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if not vc:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)


    player = self.get_player(ctx)

    # If download is False, source will be a dict which will be used later to regather the stream.
    # If download is True, source will be a discord.FFmpegPCMAudio with a VolumeTransformer.
    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)
    await player.queue.put(source)



@commands.command(name='playing', aliases=['np', 'current', 'currentsong', 'now_playing'])
async def now_playing_(self, ctx):
    """Shows the current song playing."""

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
        return await ctx.send("I'm not connected to a voice channel..", delete_after=20)

    elif ctx.author not in ctx.guild.voice_client.channel.members:
        return await ctx.send("You need to be in the voice channel first!", delete_after=20)

    player = self.get_player(ctx)
    if not player.current:
        return await ctx.send("There's nothing currently playing.", delete_after=20)

    try:
        # Remove our previous now_playing message.
        await player.np.delete()
    except discord.HTTPException:
        pass

    embednp = discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E)
    embednp.add_field(name="Currently Playing:", value=f"```fix\n{vc.source.title}```", inline=False)
    embednp.add_field(name="Requested By:", value=f"**{vc.source.requester}**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Source:", value=f"**[URL]({vc.source.web_url})**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Uploader:", value=f"**{vc.source.uploader}**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Duration:", value=f"**{datetime.timedelta(seconds=vc.source.duration)}**", inline=True)
    embednp.set_thumbnail(url=f"{vc.source.thumbnail}")
    player.np = await ctx.send(embed=embednp)
    self.music_controller = self.bot.loop.create_task(MusicPlayer(ctx).buttons_controller(ctx.guild, player.np, vc.source, ctx.channel, ctx))

async def queue_info(self, ctx):
    player = self.get_player(ctx)
    if player.queue.empty():
        return await ctx.send('**:notes: No songs currently queued.**', delete_after=5)

    upcoming = list(itertools.islice(player.queue._queue, 0, 5))

    fmt = '\n'.join(f'**`{_["title"]}`**' for _ in upcoming)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{len(upcoming)} songs queued.', description=fmt, color=0x17FD6E)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
````

Answer (score 0):

Look at your signature, `async def buttons_controller(self, guild, current, source, channel, context):` What you are looking for is source as `source = song` "the song you have requested".

Therefore you would need to add `source` in front of requester as `requester =  the member` and after this you need to define `user` as we are looking the specific requester on reaction add.

So you have this:

```
        if control == 'skip':
            if source.requester == user:
                vc.stop()
```